# Facebook Login/Google Login - Same Activity?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to give my users the option to sign in with either Google or Facebook. So far I found an example to implement a Google Sign in Flow, but I am confused if I can implement a similar Facebook Login Flow within the same Activity.

Anyone have an Idea as to handle the Logins? I was thinking about potentially defining a class to handle the Login Flows for both Google / Facebook, and perhaps just check to see which is being used when the app launches. Any Ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener, OnClickListener, OnAccessRevokedListener {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

// A magic number we will use to know that our sign-in error
// resolution activity has completed.
private static final int OUR_REQUEST_CODE = 49404;

// The core Google+ client.
private PlusClient mPlusClient;

// A flag to stop multiple dialogues appearing for the user.
private boolean mResolveOnFail;

// We can store the connection result from a failed connect()
// attempt in order to make the application feel a bit more
// responsive for the user.
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

// A progress dialog to display when the user is connecting in
// case there is a delay in any of the dialogs being ready.
private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // We pass through this for all three arguments, specifying the:
    // 1. Context
    // 2. Object to call onConnected and onDisconnected on
    // 3. Object to call onConnectionFailed on
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .build();

    // We use mResolveOnFail as a flag to say whether we should trigger
    // the resolution of a connectionFailed ConnectionResult.
    mResolveOnFail = false;

    // Connect our sign in, sign out and disconnect buttons.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.authButton).setOnClickListener(this);

    // Configure the ProgressDialog that will be shown if there is a
    // delay in presenting the user with the next sign in step.
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "Start");
    // Every time we start we want to try to connect. If it
    // succeeds we'll get an onConnected() callback. If it
    // fails we'll get onConnectionFailed(), with a result!
    mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "Stop");
    // It can be a little costly to keep the connection open
    // to Google Play Services, so each time our activity is
    // stopped we should disconnect.
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.v(TAG, "ConnectionFailed");
    // Most of the time, the connection will fail with a
    // user resolvable result. We can store that in our
    // mConnectionResult property ready for to be used
    // when the user clicks the sign-in button.
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        mConnectionResult = result;
        if (mResolveOnFail) {
            // This is a local helper function that starts
            // the resolution of the problem, which may be
            // showing the user an account chooser or similar.
            startResolution();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // Yay! We can get the oAuth 2.0 access token we are using.
    Log.v(TAG, "Connected. Yay!");

    // Turn off the flag, so if the user signs out they'll have to
    // tap to sign in again.
    mResolveOnFail = false;

    // Hide the progress dialog if its showing.
    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();

    // Hide the sign in button, show the sign out buttons.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Retrieve the oAuth 2.0 access token.
    final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
            try {
                // We can retrieve the token to check via
                // tokeninfo or to pass to a service-side
                // application.
                String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                        mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // This error is recoverable, so we could fix this
                // by displaying the intent to the user.
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    task.execute((Void) null);

    // THIS IS TO CONNECT TO NAVI ACTIVITY AFTER YOU CONNECT Also makes it
    // so you cannot go back to main activity
    /*
     * if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) { Intent intent = new Intent(this,
     * NaviActivity.class); startActivity(intent); } finish();
     */
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Bye!
    Log.v(TAG, "Disconnected. Bye!");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "ActivityResult: " + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // If we have a successful result, we will want to be able to
        // resolve any further errors, so turn on resolution with our
        // flag.
        mResolveOnFail = true;
        // If we have a successful result, lets call connect() again. If
        // there are any more errors to resolve we'll get our
        // onConnectionFailed, but if not, we'll get onConnected.
        mPlusClient.connect();
    } else if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
        // If we've got an error we can't resolve, we're no
        // longer in the midst of signing in, so we can stop
        // the progress spinner.
        mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.sign_in_button:
        Log.v(TAG, "Tapped sign in");
        if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            // Show the dialog as we are now signing in.
            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
            // Make sure that we will start the resolution (e.g. fire the
            // intent and pop up a dialog for the user) for any errors
            // that come in.
            mResolveOnFail = true;
            // We should always have a connection result ready to resolve,
            // so we can start that process.
            if (mConnectionResult != null) {
                startResolution();
            } else {
                // If we don't have one though, we can start connect in
                // order to retrieve one.
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
        break;

    case R.id.sign_out_button:
        Log.v(TAG, "Tapped sign out");
        // We only want to sign out if we're connected.
        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            // Clear the default account in order to allow the user
            // to potentially choose a different account from the
            // account chooser.
            mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();

            // Disconnect from Google Play Services, then reconnect in
            // order to restart the process from scratch.
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();

            // Hide the sign out buttons, show the sign in button.
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        break;

    // THIS SHOULD NOT BE NEEDED, MUST SWITCH ACTIVITIES UPON AUTHORIZATION
    case R.id.authButton:
        Log.v(TAG, "Switch Activities");

        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    NaviActivity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
        break;

    default:
        // Unknown id.
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccessRevoked(ConnectionResult status) {
    // mPlusClient is now disconnected and access has been revoked.
    // We should now delete any data we need to comply with the
    // developer properties. To reset ourselves to the original state,
    // we should now connect again. We don't have to disconnect as that
    // happens as part of the call.
    mPlusClient.connect();

    // Hide the sign out buttons, show the sign in button.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/**
 * A helper method to flip the mResolveOnFail flag and start the resolution
 * of the ConnenctionResult from the failed connect() call.
 */
private void startResolution() {
    try {
        // Don't start another resolution now until we have a
        // result from the activity we're about to start.
        mResolveOnFail = false;
        // If we can resolve the error, then call start resolution
        // and pass it an integer tag we can use to track. This means
        // that when we get the onActivityResult callback we'll know
        // its from being started here.
        mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, OUR_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        // Any problems, just try to connect() again so we get a new
        // ConnectionResult.
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set both fragments (facebook and google) in the layout that you use as login and in another to receive the session validated

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:layout_below="@id/authButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then use al functions required by each one

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener {
//google
private PlusClient plusClient;
private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog;
private ConnectionResult connectionResult;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
//face
private LoginButton buttonLoginLogout;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
static Usuario appusuario;
static String urldelogin="algo";
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Log.e("usuario", "si hay sesion");
            // make request to the /me API
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Log.e("usuario", "si hay usuario");
                        buildUserInfoDisplay(user);
                        //start another activity
                        }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}   

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}   

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR &&
            resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            connectionResult = null;
            plusClient.connect();
        }
}   

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}   


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
public static void buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {

    appusuario=new Usuario(user.getName(),user.getUsername());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    buttonLoginLogout = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    buttonLoginLogout.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_status"));

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    buttonLoginLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    plusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .build();

    connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Conectando...");

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (!plusClient.isConnected())
            {
                if (connectionResult == null)
                {
                    connectionProgressDialog.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                    }
                    catch (SendIntentException e)
                    {
                        connectionResult = null;
                        plusClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    plusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    plusClient.disconnect();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
        //nombre
        String accountName = plusClient.getAccountName();
       //cuenta con mail
        Person accountperson=plusClient.getCurrentPerson();
        String personName = accountperson.getDisplayName();
        Log.e("Google +", "Conectado");
        //start another activity

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected()
    {
        Log.e("Google +", "Desconectado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (connectionProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            if (result.hasResolution())
            {
                try
                {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                }
                catch (SendIntentException e)
                {
                    plusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
        connectionResult = result;

    }
      }
```

in the new activity place the same functions to validate the sesion and use

```
if (session.isOpened()) { }
```

to hide google login button or

```
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {

    }
```

to hide facebook login button