# Google and Facebook login in single activity android

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

I have to implement google login and facebook login inside one activity. Its working fine with different activity.

[image]

If anyone have any idea about this will be great appreciated.

Comment: @Tanayaagarwal Please follow the SO rules. Without any tried or code  we can't help you. Sorry and please [take a look](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266384/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-asking-about-how-to-achieve-something-without-ha)

Comment: @Tanayaagarwal This site is not provide the idea. Is about programming, Q & A with code, Code implementation with different ways, etc.. if you really want an idea then go to `Quora.com`. This is the best site for ideas...

Comment: @Tanayaagarwal Any thing other...... expect the **idea**

Comment: now anything else....moderators are here so add whatever comment you want.

Answer (score 2):

Apply That that's work properly....

========================

```
TextView txtStatus;
LoginButton login_button;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);
    initiallizeControls();
    loginWithFb();

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // Customizing G+ button
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.project.loginapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
            Log.e("hash key", something);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    }

}

private void initiallizeControls(){
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
    login_button=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
}
private void loginWithFb(){
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            txtStatus.setText("Login Success\n"+loginResult.getAccessToken());
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomePage.class);
            startActivity(a);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            txtStatus.setText("Login Cancelled");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            txtStatus.setText("Login Error: "+error.getMessage() );

        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    Intent gmail = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomePage.class);

}


private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}
private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
        //.thumbnail(0.5f)
        //.crossFade()
        //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        //.into(imgProfilePic);

        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            signOut();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}

/*@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939099/facebook-login-google-login-same-activity) you have an example.

But it's can be out of date (2013). Here is documentation about [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android), and [google plus](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in).

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the answer in 2021, Tailor vinay's answer didn't work for me.

However, this worked for me.

**MainActivity.java:**
*I'm only including things I've changed to Tailor vinay's code.

Full MainActivity.java at end.*

```
import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private LoginButton btnFbLogin;
[...]
    private SignInButton btnGooSignIn;


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("DEPRECATION")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //allocation variables to their respective buttons/images/etc
        btnFbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
        //changed sign in button to btnGooSignIn and btnFbLogin
        btnGooSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_google_sign_in);
        
[...]

        btnGooSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);
        initiallizeControls();
        //loginWithFb(); //removed from here


[...]

    private void initiallizeControls() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        txtStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
        //added calling FB login button here
        btnFbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
    }
    
[...]

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_google_sign_in:
                signInWithGoogle();
                break;

            //added a case for when FB login button is clicked
            case R.id.btn_facebook_login:
                loginWithFb();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }
    
[...]
}
```

**My activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_facebook_login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title" />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_google_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_facebook_login">

    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_google_sign_in" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgProfilePic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign out"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_revoke_access"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_revoke_access"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Revoke access"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="84dp"></LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This is my build.gradle (Module), if it helps:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<CENSORED>"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml if it also helps:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<CENSORED>">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.<CENSORED>">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**FULL MainActivity.java: (with comments)**

```
package <CENSORED>;

import ...

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private LoginButton btnFbLogin;
    private TextView status;
    public CallbackManager callbackManager;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnGooSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtStatus, txtName, txtEmail;


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("DEPRECATION")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //allocation variables to their respective buttons/images/etc
        btnFbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
        btnGooSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_google_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

        // when button clicked, stay on this activity
        btnGooSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);
        initiallizeControls();

        //Declaring GoogleSignInOptions to sign in via email
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        //Connecting the GoogleSignInOptions to the API client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Customizing Google Sign In button
        btnGooSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        btnGooSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        try {
            //Creating a hash code for the Google Sign In with exceptions for different scenarios.
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("<CENSORED>", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }

    }

    //Declaring the callbackManager, what the txtStatus and Facebook login buttons are
    private void initiallizeControls() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        txtStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
        btnFbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
    }

    // Specifying logging into Facebook (Google sign in bypassed), ans what happens if successful, user cancels the action, or if it fails.
    private void loginWithFb() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                txtStatus.setText("Login Success\n" + loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                txtStatus.setText("Login Cancelled");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                txtStatus.setText("Login Error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }

    //For Google Sign in, when the Google sign in is completed, this handles its result by sending the result to the handleSignInResult();
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    //Signing in with Google and sending the user to a new intent/page when finished
    private void signInWithGoogle() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        Intent gmail = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

    }

    // To sign out the user from Google
    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    // To allow the user to revoke access to Google Sign in.
    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }
    
    //This sets the user details from Google and inserts them into text or image views. This was just used for testing originally.
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            String email = acct.getEmail();

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);

            //External directory that assists in inserting images into ImageViews.
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
            .into(imgProfilePic);

            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    //This resolves the question, "what happens when user clicks Button X, Y or Z?"
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_google_sign_in:
                signInWithGoogle();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_facebook_login:
                loginWithFb();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    //This is code directly from the Google Tutorial that wasn't coded correctly for this activity.
    /*@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}*/

    //Google's Sign in that deals with the result of the Google Sign in and updates the buttons to be hidden/visible.
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // If the connection fails to sign in with Google, it is logged.
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);
    }

    //Shows thw progress of the Google sign in.
    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null){
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    //When the Google Sign N progress is finished (regardless of result), the progress bar is hidden.
    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    // This changes the visibility of certain buttons, depending on what buttons are needed
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnGooSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            btnGooSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```